# Monthly Average from Daily data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In column A I have the days dd/mm/yyyy and it goes all the way from now until year 2000. In column B I have numeric data specific to that date. How can I find the monthly averages for the data without having to do it for each month manually. Is there a formulae I can use and just scroll down to find the averages for each month. Thank you.

Comment: Insert a pivot table and aggregate by `month` or `week` or `quarter` or whatever else you want.

Comment: take a look at the formula AVERAGEIF if your version of excel supports its.

Answer (score 1):

IF you cannot get AVERAGEIF or AVERAGEIFS working for you, you may be able to fall back to this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26>=(EOMONTH(E$2,-1)+1))*($A$2:$A$26<=EOMONTH(E$2,0))*$B$2:$B$26)/SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26>=(EOMONTH(E$2,-1)+1))*($A$2:$A$26<=EOMONTH(E$2,0))),"NO DATES")
```

IF you cannot get IFERROR working in your version of excel then you can use this formula but you will get an error of #div/0 when no dates are found.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26>=(EOMONTH(E$2,-1)+1))*($A$2:$A$26<=EOMONTH(E$2,0))*$B$2:$B$26)/SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$26>=(EOMONTH(E$2,-1)+1))*($A$2:$A$26<=EOMONTH(E$2,0)))
```

This assumes your month you are looking for is in E2 and perhaps copied horizontally.  if your months are listed vertically change the E$2 to $E2.  You will also have to enter your dates that you are looking for in an excel date format including the year, month, and some day dying the month.

If you have the AVERAGEIFS available to you it is the preferred way to go.  use the following:

```
=AVERAGEIFS($B$2:$B$26,$A$2:$A$26,">="&EOMONTH(E2,-1)+1,$A$2:$A$26,"<="&EOMONTH(E2,0))
```

Proof of concept

[image: Proof of concept]